# Git - Restore folder which was introduced and deleted in unknown commits

Tags: git, github

I am facing the following situation: There is supposed to be a folder on the 'dev' branch. This folder was introduced at some point and deleted at some point in the last 3 months. We do not have the commit where this folder was introduced, and we do not know the commit in which this folder was removed. Is it possible to determine when the folder was introduced and then removed, knowing only its name?

I don't want to walk thru the whole history manually, as that effort is < than creating the folder with all files inside. Asked ChatGPT, proposed to use reflog, and one more command was suggested here - git log --diff-filter=D --since="2023-04-01" but both of those approaches mean I need to go thru the whole git history..

Thanks in advance :)